# Plausible reason why the androids would kick out all the humans?

Tags: android

So, it’s the day after the nuclear apocalypse. At an android factory, a group of androids are planning to create a new community. This community is integral to the plot of my story. Fresno, were the factory is, is supposed to be a human free zone that only the occasional merchant and trader travel to. In the past, the robots gathered collections of weaponry and chased all the humans out of town. The robots are usually emotionless and stoic, and never use violence unless necessary for self preservation. What might be a plausible reason why the androids chased the humans out of town?

Comment: There are a lot of "why would [AI/Robots/Androids/Etc] take over humans?" questions on this site.  Please take the time to review those questions using our search feature.  If you do not find an answer to your question, then please explain why your question is different from the others.  Thanks!

Comment: What a silly choice of a duplicate. Its answer concerns how to pacify humans. This question is asks for a plausible reason for the androids run humans out of town. These are distinctly different propositions. I'm voting to reopen. Hopefully persons voting close because of duplication will in future read the possible duplicate question and its answers more carefully. This way they can make sure the possible duplicates are actual duplicates.

Comment: I'd suggest good taste, but I might be biased.

Comment: @a4android: What do you mean, android man? He’s one of them, rally the firing squad

Comment: A puny human! We must missed him. We collected all the weapons, remember. Better start running now.

Comment: @a4android: Oh no, I’m gone. Bye bye

Comment: @JBH Useful advice about searching other [AI/robots/androids/etc.] questions. I decided to do the search myself. Yes there are a reasonable number of them. While might have related scenarios among them, none of them are close enough to be an answer to this question. How do you expect anyone to explain their question is different from other AI etc etc questions even when they are?  You can confirm this yourself by doing your own recommended search. There's always the chance I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, self-preservation.  Even if humans are weaker or less intelligent than the androids, their emotions make them a threat.  Especially true if the humans have much greater numbers.  The androids may see it as safer to expel all the humans rather than risk any chance of an anti-android pogrom.

Remember, being stoic and emotionless doesn't necessarily mean noble.  Sure, they won't hate humans, but they won't have any compassion for them either.  If their cold calculations show humans to be more trouble than they're worth, they won't hesitate to banish or kill them all.